# Stripes URLBinding defaulting to wrong URL

Tags: java, stripes, urlbinding

Pretty simple, I have two Beans, each with their own URLBindings:

```
@UrlBinding("/api/location/states/{state}")
@UrlBinding("/api/location/states/{state}/cities/{city}")
```

The first URL works as expected, but if I visit the second URL, Stripes matches it to the first URL instead. I've tried different variations of the URL formats, none seem to work.

EDIT: It looks like the first parameter is including part of the URL, for example, hitting the second URL gives me `state=virginia/cities/richmond`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to implement ActionBean in my second class. I'll leave this question active in case someone is running into the same problems.